# How to use an ArrayAdapter with Spinner Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to create dropdown list (Spinner) in  AndroidStudio (Kotlin).

So, I create `convert_from_spinner` on my Activity. Then I tried to add values to the list, but IDE gives me an error:

```
package com.currency_converter.ui.home

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.ClipData
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import com.currency_converter.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService

//

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val values : Array<String> = arrayOf("USD", "UAH", "GBD", "EUR", "BIT", "RUB")
        var data = ArrayList<String>()

        data.add("USD")
        data.add("RUB")

      val convert_from_spinner: Spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.convert_from_spinner)
        convert_from_spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data)


        return root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val values : Array<String> = arrayOf("USD", "UAH", "GBD", "EUR", "BIT", "RUB")
        var data = ArrayList<String>()
        data.add("USD")
        data.add("RUB")
        convert_from_spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data)
    }
```

And error

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

<init>(Context, Int, Array<(out) TypeVariable(T)!>)
  where T = TypeVariable(T) for 
  constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: Array<(out) T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
<init>(Context, Int, Int)
  where T = TypeVariable(T) for 
  constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, textViewResourceId: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
<init>(Context, Int, (Mutable)List<TypeVariable(T)!>)
  where T = TypeVariable(T) for 
  constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(context: Context, resource: Int, objects: (Mutable)List<T!>) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter Alt+Shift+Enter Alt+Enter
```

[image]

I've tried to use 'activity' or 'getActivity' as I heard [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48325639/how-to-use-an-arrayadapter-in-a-fragment-with-kotlin)

But it doesn't workin too:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `requireContext()` or `requireActivity()` instead of `this` or `activity`.

`Fragment`, unlike `activity`, is not inherited from the `Context class`, which means it cannot be passed into arguments as a context. The above 2 methods just give the opportunity to get the context inside any Fragment

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use this method in onCreateView not in onCreate

Make sure your Fragment import is

> import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

```
    val values : Array<String> = arrayOf("USD", "UAH", "GBD", "EUR", "BIT", "RUB")
    var data = ArrayList<String>()
    data.add("USD")
    data.add("RUB")
    val convert_from_spinner: Spinner = root.findViewById(R.id.<your spinner_id>)
    convert_from_spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(ac, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data)
```

Comment: `Type mismatch. 
Required:
Context
Found:
FragmentActivity? `  I've tried it to. but not working.

Comment: And this ```      val activity_var: Activity? = activity
        convert_from_spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity_var, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data) ```is not working too

Comment: I tried to do this in onCreate. onViewCreated onCreateView, but in no function  it didn't work

Comment: Updated the answer just paste it in your onCreateView

Comment: No. The same problem: Waiting Contex. Geted Activity? https://imgur.com/a/6d6queO

Comment: Make sure your fragment import is import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

Comment: Let me know if it is fixed or not ?

Comment: It's fixed . I added own answer. Thanks